# Server up and running but webpage not rendering on heroku local

Tags: reactjs, git, heroku

I am in the process of deploying a dynamic, React.js app to Heroku and wanted to test it out by using 'heroku local' to see if it works before pushing it to Heroku. Everything seemed to be working fine with the server - my database console.log message logs to the terminal signifying everything is going well - but when I try to access the website which is on localhost:5000, I get an error message of 'Cannot GET /' and the console prints a message saying , 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'. My React.js files are all within the build folder which in conjunction with all of the other files, were pushed to git and commited, but for some reason my files are not showing up. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me determine what went wrong. Sorry if my question is a little vague; please let me know if I can clarify something in better detail as I am fairly new to programming.

**I've added a proxy to one of my package.json files to help with url routing; possibly this could be causing the issue?**

[image]**Also, if it helps at all, a photo of my folders within Visual Studio code are listed below:**

[image]